# route request to controller based on route parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I want to route request to specific version controller based on version number in URI.

for example,

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "APIV2",
            routeTemplate: "BlogFeed/{version}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, controller = "BlogFeedV2"}
        );
```

What I want is that based on version route parameter I want to route request to that versioned controller.  so if version route parameter is v2, that request should be handled by BlogFeedV2.  Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

why not :

```
  routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "APIV2",
        routeTemplate: "BlogFeed/v2/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, controller = "BlogFeedV2"}
    );       
  routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "APIV1",
        routeTemplate: "BlogFeed/v1/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, controller = "BlogFeedV1"}
    );
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought about that but is there any other way to do that?  Otherwise I end up having each route entry for each version.

Comment: You can load them from settings on the fly or add a separate method just for API versions. But Honestly if you do a version every 3 months you'll only be at 6 when mvc 5 is live